# Count rows for two columns using two different clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm after a CTE which I want to return two columns, one with the total number of 1's and one with the total number of 0's. Currently I can get it to return one column with the total number of 1's using:

```
WITH getOnesAndZerosCTE
AS (

    SELECT COUNT([message]) AS TotalNo1s
    FROM dbo.post
    WHERE dbo.checkletters([message]) = 1

    --SELECT COUNT([message]) AS TotalNo0s
    --FROM dbo.post
    --WHERE dbo.checkletters([message]) = 0

    )
SELECT * FROM getOnesAndZerosCTE;
```

How do I have a second column called TotalNo0s in the same CTE which I have commented in there to show what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation:

```
WITH getOnesAndZerosCTE AS(
    SELECT
        TotalNo1s = SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.checkletters([message]) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        TotalNo0s = SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.checkletters([message]) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM post
)
SELECT * FROM getOnesAndZerosCTE;
```

Answer (score 1):

For using COUNT() directly just be aware that it counts any NON-NULL values. You can omit the ELSE condition which implicitly returns NULL if not stated

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.checkletters([message]) = 1 THEN 1 END) TotalNo1s 
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.checkletters([message]) = 0 THEN 1 END) TotalNo0s
FROM post
```

or, explicitly state NULL

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.checkletters([message]) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) TotalNo1s 
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.checkletters([message]) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) TotalNo0s
FROM post
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without CTE

```
select    count(message) total,  
          dbo.checkletters(message) strLength 
from      post
group by  dbo.checkletters(message)
having    dbo.checkletters(message) in  (1, 2) //All the messages with length 1 or 2
```